# Horror movie about family driving down a country road

Tags: story-identification, horror

This American horror movie came out in the mid to late 90s / early 2000s.

It centres around a family going on a vacation. Mother, father and two teenagers.

They're driving down a highway somewhere in the states and I think the father suggests taking a short cut down a long country road.

Lots of freaky stuff happens on this country road, they crash and die a few times I think but they keep waking up back in the car.

Each member of the family flips out one after another and they attack each other and everyone dies but they keep waking up back in the car.

Other weird stuff happens, at one point the mother sustains a serious blow to the back of her head, she goes insane and starts picking out her own brains and eating them. Which is nice...

I know there is a hearse following them for the entire journey though.

I can't remember the ending, but I think at least one of them survives and wakes up in a hospital and the hearse is parked outside.

I'm not sure if they ever have any interaction with the hearse driver or if you ever find out what's going on with the hearse.

This sounds like a lot of jibberish, hopefully someone can decipher it and help me out!

Comment: " the father suggests taking a short cut down a long country road." Εvery horror movie starts by someone suggesting something stupid

Comment: @Shevliaskovic horrors wouldn't exist without stupid people

Comment: The main character decided to: "read a Latin manuscript aloud", "buy a creepy antique", "ignore a jar of teeth", "take a *shortcut* through an abandoned town", "build a house in Suicide Forest".

Comment: @GorchestopherH At least land would be cheap in Suicide Forest... Buy it all up and rename it Happiness Valley? That's money in the bank!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly "[Dead End](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_End_%282003_film%29)" (2003)

Features a family who take a shortcut, hit another car, but are still alive. They die repeatedly. A hearse is featured throughout. The full description is in the Wikipedia link above.

Comment: That's the one! I recognise the actor playing the father! Cheers!